# My PC loses Internet connection despite being connected to a local network

Tags: internet

I have a Ubuntu PC at work and it is connected to the local network. Lately (possibly after some updates and the version upgrade, but not 100% sure) it started to lose its Internet connection while still being on. It's really inconvenient as I cannot ssh to it. When I come once a week to the office and replug the cable, the connection gets restored. So I assume that it triggers the system to initialise the connection again, or something. While I'm at the computer, it has no problems. But then when I leave, after some hours it goes offline again.

I suppose that something triggers the system to lose the connection. Apart from a fresh system install, is it possible to do anything to quickly fix this issue? Perhaps run some script that would force to renew the connection? Like once an hour turn off and then turn on the network?

Comment: There is no information here that could be used to help solve this problem. What version of Ubuntu? Error messages. Contents of log files?

Comment: It's probably a bad cable.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Or, use `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up running this script in the background, inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133931/automatically-restarting-network-connection, which helped me to solve the problem. The connection still goes off from time to time, but importantly, it then gets restored thanks to the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  if ! ping -I eno1 -c 1 google.com; 
  then
    echo $(date) "No network connection" >> network_out
    ifconfig eno1 down
    sleep 5
    ifconfig eno1 up
  fi
  sleep 600
done
```

Here, `eno1` is the name of my ethernet interface. In a loop, if it cannot ping google.com, then it shuts down the network connection, sleeps for 5 seconds, and then turns the connection on again.